# Zero knowledge proofs in practice

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

What are the practical problems of using zero knowledge proofs, for instance in the field of authentication?

Comment: Related, unanswered question of mine: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48102/security-of-zero-knowledge-proof-protocols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there are very few practical barriers to deploying zero-knowledge proofs. They've been deployed in everything from [anonymous credentials](https://www.zurich.ibm.com/identity_mixer/) to [cryptocurrencies](https://z.cash/) to [privacy-preserving survey systems](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/681.pdf). Very fast academic systems have been developed which use zero-knowledge proofs for [privacy-preserving distributed machine learning](https://www.henrycg.com/files/academic/papers/nsdi17prio.pdf). This last example hasn't been deployed yet, but clearly is fast and scalable enough to be used in practice.