# Zero Knowledge Proof (ZKP) Threat Vectors / Attack Vectors

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

What are some Threat Vectors / Attack Vectors of Zero Knowledge Proof (ZKP)?

Comment: This question seems unclear and overly broad.

Comment: it is not broad. I wish to understand if there are any attack mechanisms

Comment: attack mechanisms on what? On arbitrary zero knowledge proofs? By definition, an arbitrary zero-knowledge proof is a generic one that does satisfy the appropriate security property - hence, one for which, by definition, there is no attack. Do you want a list of common attack on possible strategies for building ZKP? A list of the things one must be careful about when designing a ZKP? In both case, I agree with @Maeher that this is a very broad question, and it's not obvious to guess what exactly you want to know. Can you reformulate and give us more details about what you have in mind?

Comment: stop marking down guys. this is an excellent qns. those who mark the question down is not helpful to a beginner like myself

Comment: Please, provide a bit more context, what you've looked at, what kind of zero knowledge proofs you're interested in, etc.

Comment: yes this question itself is the context. I am a beginner who is looking to use ZKP at scale so please be beginner friendly. Many, many thanks...

Comment: As a heads-up, please note “[Do we accept basic level/homework questions?
Yes, we do. However, please provide an indication of what you are not understanding/need clarification on and your attempts at solving it, so we have a clear indication of where you are stuck. This goes for all questions, not just homework. If you have just written out your assignment, your question will be closed.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)” Our help center has some related tips on how to ask better questions too. Hope that helps…

Comment: Related, I think, and possibly interesting for OP: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48102/security-of-zero-knowledge-proof-protocols

Answer (score 3):

In general there are different types of Threat Vectors or Attack Vectors like Brute-Force and Dictionary Attacks, etc. But regarding the Zero-Knowledge Proof, I got some information that are given below:

Attacks of Zero-Knowledge Proof:

1. Impersonation  – One entity pretends to be another.
2. Replay – uses an impersonation involving use of information from a single previous protocol execution on the same or different verifier.
3. Interleaving – an impersonation involving a selective combination of information from one or more previous protocol executions.
4. Reflection – an interleaving attack involving sending information from an ongoing protocol execution back to the originator.
5. Forced Delay – an adversary that intercepts a message and relays it later.
6. Chosen-text – when an adversary chooses specific challenges in an attempt to gain information about the secret.
7. The Grandmaster Problem (MitM attack)
8. The Mafia problem

Disadvantages of Zero-Knowledge Proof:

1. Limited – Translation might be necessary if secret is not a number.
2. Lengthy – As it has almost 2k entity, it takes a lot of time to compute.
3. Imperfect – The Intruder can still intercept the message (i.e. messages to the Verifier might be modified or destroyed)
4. A zero-knowledge proof is only as good as the secret it is trying to conceal.
5. Zero-knowledge proofs of identities in particular are problematic.

Comment: @ Nathan : two more attacks are there: The Grandmaster Problem (MiM attack) and the Mafia problem which I now included in my answer.